# Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in E:\wamp\www\arihant\view_details.php on line 27 getting this error

Tags: php, validation, explode

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['b_no'])){ 
  $bno=$_GET['b_no'];

  include("connect.php");
  $query19="select * from billing where `b_no`=$bno";

  $rs19=$conn->execute($query19);

  if($rs19){
         $itm=explode(',',$rs19['item']);
         $qty=explode(',',$rs19['qty']);
          $r=count($itm); 


            for($i=0;$i<=$r;$i++) {  
                       if(isset($itm[$i]) && isset($qty[$i]))    {
                                  echo "item".$itm[$i]; 
                                  echo "qty".$qty[$i];      
                              echo "<br>";  
                        }
            }

    }
    else {  
    echo "no records found";
    }
}

  else { 
  echo "enter bill no";
  }
?>
```

I am getting this warning every time when entering the b_no which is not in the database. I am using Microsoft Access 2007 as the backend, and getting this warning:

> Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in on line 27

Comment: Add this code before of explode: `if (is_object($rs19['item'])) print_r($rs19['item']); if(is_object($rs19['qty'])) print_r($rs19['qty'])`, and publish outputting result here

Comment: in my above code if i pass a b_no which is in table the code gets executed properly . but if i pass a value which is not present in the table then problem occurs.
means i am not able to validate my query.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$rs19` contains a result set **not** an associative array. You must fetch a row from that result set in order to get the associative array you are looking for.

Not sure what php/mysql library you are using but it should look something like this.

```
$row19 = $rs19->fetch();
```

Comment: in my above code if i pass a b_no which is in table the code gets executed properly . but if i pass a value which is not present in the table then problem occurs. means i am not able to validate my query

Comment: have you tried `var_dump` to see what `$rs19` contains? What php / mysql library are you using.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not in the database , then you should perform a check before using `explode()`

```
 if($rs19>0){
     //there is a record
    }
    else {  
    echo "no records found";
    }
```

Comment: they do preform a check

Comment: @LoganMurphy what do you mean

Comment: They do preform a check. They just don't compare to 0. Your test will evaluate to whatever theirs does I believe. (Line 10)

Comment: Notice: Object of class variant could not be converted to int 
showing this after doing above modification

Answer (score 0):

As a quick and dirty workaround, you can just change this:

```
if($rs19){
     $itm=explode(',',$rs19['item']);
     $qty=explode(',',$rs19['qty']);
```

To this:

```
if($rs19 && is_string($rs19['item'] && is_string($rs19['qty']){
     $itm=explode(',',$rs19['item']);
     $qty=explode(',',$rs19['qty']);
```

Comment: for every input it is saying "no records found"

after changing to above code.

Comment: Very strange... Ok, try to change it back to `if($rs19)`, and after that, find input, that leads to "warning:  explode()....", and when you would be sure that you found it, add `print_r($rs19['item']);` and `print_r($rs19['qty']);` before line `$itm=explode(',',$rs19['item']);`, and tell me, what it outputs in that case.